# async\await при считывании таблицы

Tags: c#, async-await, android-asynctask

Есть метод, который считывает ячейки таблицы xlsx и записывает их в List. При синхронном выполнении программа зависает на 20-30 секунд пока не закончится операция.

Читал про async await на хабре. Но так и не смог понять как воспользоваться данной технологией в своем методе.

Код метода,

```
public static  List<Drom_object> ReadMassive(string path) // метод, вызываемый при чтении таблицы.
{
    drom_massive = new List<Drom_object>(); // инициализируем лист.

    try { 
    FileInfo existingFile = new FileInfo(path);
    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
    {

        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];   // данные всегда на первом листе. 

        int row = GetDimensionRows(worksheet); // узнаем сколько строк в таблице.


        for (int r = 1; r <= row; r++) // считываем все строки
        {
            string[] buff = new string[18]; // создаем буфер строки эксель из 18 ячеек. (18 колонок)
            for (int i = 1; i < 19; i++) // сканируем 18 колонок (с 1 по 18)
            {
                try
                {
                    Value = null; //убираем мусор

                    Value = worksheet.Cells[r, i].Value.ToString(); // получаем значение ячейки
                }
                catch (NullReferenceException)
                {
                    Value = "empty";
                    System.Console.WriteLine("JDC: обработано пустое значение ячейки");
                }
                buff[i-1] = Value.ToString(); // Засовываем отсканированные стролбцы в буфер
            }

            if (buff[0] == "empty" && buff[1] == "empty" && buff[2] == "empty" && buff[3] == "empty" && buff[4] == "empty" && buff[5] == "empty")
            // если первые пять ячеек пустые - значит остальные проверять смысла нет, т.к. это пустая строка.
            {
                // ничего не делаем
            }
            else // но если в строке что то есть, надо понять, либо это глобальная категория, либо строка заголовков либо товарная строка.
            {

                if (buff[0] != "empty" && buff[1] == "empty" && buff[2] == "empty") // если только первая ячейка не пустая значит это ЗАГОЛОВОК (global_category).
                {
                    global_category = buff[0];

                }
                else 
                {
                    if (!buff[0].Contains("Наименование товара") || !buff[2].Contains("Марка") || !buff[17].Contains("Фотография"))  // Если это не строка категорий
                    {
                        // Значит это строка с товарной позицией, и нам пора добавлять товар в ListDrom
                        Drom_object new_good = new Drom_object(); //класс дром_обьект принимает 16 позиций. выбираем из буфера нужные и вставляем
                        new_good.SetData(
                            buff[0],
                            buff[1],
                            buff[2],
                            buff[3],
                            buff[5],
                            buff[6],
                            buff[7],
                            buff[8],
                            buff[9],
                            buff[11],
                            buff[12],
                            buff[13],
                            buff[14],
                            buff[16],
                            buff[17],
                            global_category);

                        drom_massive.Add(new_good); // наполняем обьект нужными данными и суем их в лист.

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
    catch (System.ArgumentNullException)
    {

    }

    read_ok = true; // после того как наполнение закончено, поднимаем флаг
    return drom_massive; // Возвращаем наш массив обьектов

}
```

Как мне сделать этот метод асинхронным?  Куда добавить await...

В во всех примерах await ставится к методу который уже где то за рамками примера определен и прекрасно работает.

Когда я попытался создать асинхронный метод который вызывал бы асинхронно вышеописанный метод - также получил ошибку при компиляции...

У меня еще несколько таких же методов которые участвуют в I\O.  Если бы я понял как сделать этот, я бы смог по такому же принципу сделать остальные,

И еще вопрос, хотелось бы вызывать  этот асинк метод из класса формы, чтобы не заморачиваться с доступом к Progress bar.

Если не сложно приведите небольшой скетч в котором асинхронно выполнялось бы считывание данных, и было реализована отправка статуса операции (процент выполнения) в свойство какой нибудь формы.

Comment: Если программа зависает на 20-30 секунд - это повод взять в руки профилировщик и найти самое узкое место. Это гораздо более надёжный способ, чем "я слышал о технологии ХХХ, как бы мне её применить сюда"? Очень часто бывает, что переход не срабатывает. Или срабатывает, но из-за неумения в технологию и первого входа делаются ещё больше ошибок и технология откладывается в сторону. Я серьёзно: возьмите профилировщик и посмотрите, на чём затык. Лучше искать не там где светло, а там где потерял.

Comment: Ну если вы это делаете в UI потоке, то завтык в этом. Делайте в другом потоке

Comment: ясно понятно что UI потоке, потому что как сделать в другом потоке я не знаю, я думал что async await как раз и освободит UI поток....

Comment: @JulianDelCampo Ну так-то асинхронность работает только с IO-операциями, а тут вы все считали полностью в память => вам нужно это делать в отдельном Task'е.

Comment: вы можете пояснить свои слова кодом, мне как человеку, не умеющему пока в потоки и асинхронность. 
попробовал сунуть метод в другой поток, но теперь не ясно как возвращать оттуда данные...

  public static void RunReadInOtherThread(string path)
        {
            List<Drom_object> list = new List<Drom_object>();
            Thread tread_test = new Thread(() => ReadMassive(path)); 
            tread_test.Start();   // Выполнить в новом потоке.
     
        }
что будет происходить с основным потоком когда запустится этот... как чекать статус выполнения потока из основного потока?

Comment: А смысл повторять одно и тоже многократно, если это описано в документации? Вот почитайте метанит https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/12.2.php

Answer (score 0):

Пока не удалось разобраться с Acync Await вместо этого был использован более старый класс Thread:

Вызов метода происходит так:

```
  private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button2.Enabled = false;



        Thread t = new Thread(delegate () { Work_with_massive.ReadMassive(this, Work_with_massive.GlobalPath); });
        t.Start();   
    }
```

К сожалению данный метод (подход) не лишен недостатков:
 1. Таким образом нельзя вернуть какие то данные из метода, сообщить можно методу только один параметр типа Object (насколько я понял)
 2. И нет отчетности о проценте исполнения задачи.

Comment: а для того чтобы из метода ReadMassive можно было менять обьекты формы, форма передается прямо туда, а оттуда уже через Invoke идет обращение к полям